# Best way to implement read and write mutexes using pthreads?

Tags: pthreads

I've got a data structure that could be read simultaneously by 100s of threads, but naturally write/write and write/read conflicts must be avoided. My 1st attempt with pthread_mutex_lock prevented multiple reads. What would be a good way, using pthreads, to prevent write/write and write/read while allowing multiple reads?

Comment: Can you use pthreads' [native rwlocks](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_rwlock_destroy.html)?

Comment: @pilcrow: thanks, looks like what I need.

Comment: Well, then let me promote that to an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A great way would be to use the [native rwlock facility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_rwlock_destroy.html) from pthreads itself.